# How to find word in string of words and numbers

Tags: php

This is example:

```
 $haystack = "451516178jjgsjkjjssbbziznbdkbnjv.bvkljk_isikjsksjkthisjkhkjhkjh4364765467";
 $needle = "this";
```

I need true or false.
How to do that?

I think with preg_match but I dont know how.

Comment: preg_match is too much for this samll comaprison.use [`strpos()`](http://us2.php.net//manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it with regex:

```
$needle = "/this/";
echo preg_match($needle, $haystack);
```

This will return 1 one if it matches else 0

Answer (score 7):

You don't need regex to do this. As already mentioned in comments use [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos):

```
if(strpos($heystack, $needle) !== false) {
// contains
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$haystack = "451516178jjgsjkjjssbbziznbdkbnjv.bvkljk_isikjsksjkthisjkhkjhkjh4364765467";
$needle = "this";

$string = strpos($haystack, $needle);

if($string === false)
 echo "false";
else
 echo "true";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try strpos functionality.

Example:

```
$title = "this is a string123";
if ((strpos($title,'is')=== false) {
    echo 'false';
else
   echo 'true';
}
```

reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: you cannot use (!) in this case because this will fail if the occurence is in position `0` (which falls into !). you must use `=== false`

Comment: actually no problem, you better change this because some users like to downvote without an explanation. and no i wont downvote just want to clear this up